# Data table not appearing using primeReact custom reusable data table component

Tags: typescript, primereact

I have created a custom data table component, which I intend to reuse whenever I want. I created it using primeReact 8.7.3 version.

```
import React from 'react';
import { DataTable } from 'primereact/datatable';
import { Column } from 'primereact/column';

interface CustomDataTableProps {
  data: any; 
  columns: any[]; 
}

const CustomDataTable: React.FC<CustomDataTableProps> = ({ data, columns }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <DataTable value={data} stripedRows responsiveLayout="scroll">
        {columns.map((column, index) => (
          <Column key={index} field={column.field} header={column.header} />
        ))}
      </DataTable>
    </div>
  );
};

export default CustomDataTable;
```

This is the data table component which should take data in rows and columns. To check this table I used mockData from primeReact itself.

I created another mockData.tsx fil to store my data. From there I am trying to render the data table using this component and mockdata, in App.tsx as follows.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import CustomDataTable from './datatable-component/customDataTable';
import {ProductService} from './datatable-component/mockData';

export interface Product {
  id: string;
  code: string;
  name: string;
  description: string;
  image: string;
  price: number;
  category: string;
  quantity: number;
  inventoryStatus: string;
  rating: number;
}

function App() {
  const [products, setProducts] = useState<Product[]>([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true); 

  useEffect(() => {
      ProductService.getProducts().then(data => setProducts(data));
  }, []);

    const columns = [
        { field: 'code', header: 'Code' },
        { field: 'name', header: 'Name' },
        { field: 'category', header: 'Category' },
        { field: 'quantity', header: 'Quantity' },
    ];

    return (
      <div className="App">
          <h1>Custom Reusable Data Table Example</h1>
          {loading ? (
              <p>Loading...</p>
          ) && (
              <CustomDataTable data={products} columns={columns} />
          ) : null}
      </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

But this is rendering only data. The table format is not showing. I am attaching the screenshot of the data also.

[image]